# Completely remove the existence of a form for an IntelliJ GUI Designer UI build

Tags: java, class, user-interface, intellij-idea

I have created a GUI using the GUI Designer in IntelliJ IDEA, which includes the .form file as well as the bound class file.

The application runs as it is supposed to, and now I want to export the source files so that they can be used on other systems.

I know IDEA has the option to

```
Generate GUI into:  Java source code
```

but this leaves me with remnants of intelliJ such as

```
$$$setupUI$$$()   and     $$$getRootComponent$$$()
```

Is there any way to have IDEA simply generate a class with a constructor or main that initializes the GUI, without relying on these sorts of seemingly unknown calls to unknown methods?

I just want to have my data members, generate them properly, and move on without these IntelliJ things.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ uses its own library to allow you to create GUIs visually, like in visual studio. Unfortunately, this means the form code you created only makes sense to this library. If you don't want to include the weird Java code or the dll, you will need to rewrite.